# AS3 Air for Mobile MultiTouch Two onscreen buttons at once

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, multi-touch

I am developing a game for Android, and in future IOS and I need to be able to move the player with a left or right on screen control as well as have the player able to shoot simultaneously with another on screen control.

As it is I have it set up with `MouseEvent.CLICK` which works, but only one at a time. I have tried replacing my `MouseEvent.CLICK` listeners with `TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN` and adding a `TouchEvent.TOUCH_END` and setting `Multitouch.inputMode = multitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT`, but I realize in documentation `TOUCH_POINT` doesn't allow for multiple touch inputs so I am left to using `GESTURE`. I have no idea where to start with implementing this to allow for me to be able to have two buttons pressed simultaneously.

Code snippet:

```
leftControl = new Left_btn(50,430);
rightControl = new Right_btn(150,430);
dropControl = new Drop_btn(750,430);
stage.addChild(leftControl);
stage.addChild(rightControl);
stage.addChild(dropControl);
leftControl.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,player.moveLeft);
leftControl.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,player.moveLeftStop);
rightControl.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,player.moveRight);
rightControl.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,player.moveRightStop);
dropControl.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP,player.drop);
```

I also have a problem when using the buttons even without any listeners added. The whole game lags for a frame or so when taping or clicking on a button. Not sure why or how to fix this.

EDIT: By replacing the buttons with movieclips, this seems to have stopped the frame lag.

Answer (score 0):

**Frame lagging** is a major issue with Air and iOS, even on Android. You have to maintain your code for optimization.

For Multitouch try this,
[Tap, Gesture and Multitouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769394/how-to-listen-for-both-tap-and-gestures-at-the-same-time-in-adobe-air-for-ios)

To directly access iOS Touch APIs try with,

[ANE Air Native Extension](http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/2011/09/25/developing-android-extensions-for-air-3-a-beginners-guide/)

Comment: So it would be fair to say that it is not possible to do what I would like with the built-in multitouch from Adobe?